# Wordpress: How to mark (new post) fields as required

Tags: wordpress

I need to define some fields as required within the Wordpress add Post page. Does anyone know how to solve this? Especially the page thumbnail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write some jquery that checks if those fields are empty and throws an alert at the user if they aren't.

Comment: Thanks. I tought there was an native Wordpress function. jQuery sounds good because i'm familar with.